# Header and Padding trouble with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am working on the following site: http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/.

It looks great in Firefox and Chrome but when I go to the home page in Internet explorer it drops the navigation menu down along with the social media icons on the left side. Can anyone help me with finding the error in my css code so it will look correct across all browsers.

Thank you,

Matthew Minten

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are you referring to?

Comment: Please add more helpful information, what version of IE (hit f12), what is the html and css that is not correctly displaying. Adding a link to your website is ok, but please give more info.

Comment: I am using IE 10 on my current pc but it has the same problem in IE 9. Basically the Navigation Bar is supposed to be the blue bar under the header graphics and social media icons, Home/Contact links, and text resizer are all supposed to be above that. Right now all of this stuff is pushed down about 100px or more. If you look at the site in any other browser you can see what it is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it looks like you may be relying on certain HTML5 tags (nav) for your formatting, which will definitely create problems in IE.  At this stage in the game, I use HTML5 tags but I don't rely on them.  I tend to just use them to wrap my formatting, since support can be sketchy.

This may or may not be contributing to *THE* problem, but it certainly may be creating *A* problem

Comment: Isn't that what the HTML5.js file that I am using supposed to correct? I have never had this problem with any other website that I have built while using a child theme of twenty-twelve. Could it be just a CSS problem that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the following as the first line of the `<head>` if you're using HTML5 stuff:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2012/02/29/using-x-ua-compatible-to-create-durable-enterprise-web-applications.aspx

> Placing the Meta Tag Too Late: If the meta tag appears after we have had to determine the rendering engine, then you are too late. You have to include that metadata before running scripts or rendering HTML. The mode can be switched only before you’ve done any work which uses a rendering and scripting engine, otherwise we decide based on the header or the group policy.

Note - I put the `chrome=1` in there so those with [Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) installed will render using that.

Edit - apparently they're [getting rid of the Chrome Frame extension](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html).